# How to Obtain First and Last record ? One Step Solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have the following data  table.

```
 Record  Date        Price 
 A       3/1/2015    5 
 A       3/2/2015    6 
 A       3/3/2015    7 
 A       3/4/2015    10 
 B       2/1/2015    4 
 B       2/2/2015    6 
 B       2/3/2015    15 
 B       2/4/2015    2
```

How can I output a table that only shows the First price and the last price for each record for the first date in the table and the last date in the table. Output columns would be Record, First Price, Last Price. I am looking for a one step solution that is easy to implement in order to create a custom view.

The output desired would be:

```
 Record     FirstPrice   LastPrice
 A          5            10 
 B          4            2
```

Comment: what is the code you've wrote so far?

Comment: I have not written any code yet.

Comment: post a sample of the desired output along with a draft of your solution so we may help you improve it ;)

Comment: you have different dates in each record, so according to your requirements all records must be in result?

Comment: Solution:  Record  FirstPrice LastPrice
 A   5   10 
 B  4  2

Comment: Select min and max of price and group by record ....

Comment: Not trying to get min and max of price. Trying to get the price of the first occurance and price of the last occurance.

Comment: Define 'first', and note that dates in MySQL adhere to a specific format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?

```
select R.Record, FD.Price as MinPrice, LD.Price as MaxPrice
from Records R
join (
    select Price, R1.Record
    from Records R1
    where Date = (select MIN(DATE) from Records R2 where R2.Record = R1.Record)
  ) FD on FD.Record = R.Record
join (
   select Price, R1.Record
    from Records R1
    where Date = (select MAX(DATE) from Records R2 where R2.Record =     R1.Record)
  ) LD on LD.Record = R.Record
group by R.Record
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d047b/26

Comment: your solution seems pretty good, I just suggest to modify this part: select R.Record, FD.Price as Min, LD.Price as Max

Answer (score 0):

Get the min and max aggregate dates grouped by the record field and join back to the root data.  If you can have multiple records for the same record field on the same date, you will have to use min, max or avg to get just one value for that date.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1158b/3

```
SELECT anchorData.Record
,      firstRecord.Price
,      lastRecord.Price
FROM (
    SELECT Record
    ,      MIN(Date) AS FirstDate
    ,      MAX(Date) AS LastDate
    FROM   Table1
    GROUP BY Record
    ) AS anchorData
JOIN   Table1 AS firstRecord
ON     firstRecord.Record = anchorData.Record
AND    firstRecord.Date = anchorData.FirstDate
JOIN   Table1 AS lastRecord
ON     lastRecord.Record = anchorData.Record
AND    lastRecord.Date = anchorData.LastDate
```

Answer (score -1):

"in order to create a custom view."...are you looking to do this in Oracle/MySql as a CREATE VIEW or just a query/select statement?

Comment: a create view is what i will be doing.

Comment: @mituw16 has a decent answer